# Angularjs Nodejs external controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying my first app with the full MEAN stack but actually I'm stuck at definition of controllers/template outside from the first page.

I'm able to reach the various templates I created, but I can't succeed on find a way to bind the controller.

Here are my files

**app.js** which is located in the root directory

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var test = require('./routes/test');

var app = express();   
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/test', test);       
module.exports = app;
```

**angularApp.js** located in public/javascripts/ where I tried both appending path, without path, with extension, without extension...

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, 

$urlRouterProvider) {   
$stateProvider  
.state('home', {        
url: '/home',       
templateUrl: '/home.html',      
controller: 'MainCtrl'  })  
.state('test', {        
url: '/test',       
templateUrl: 'presentation/test.html',      
controller: 'controller/CustomCtrl.js'  
});

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home'); }]);
```

**CustomCtrl.js** this is my controller located in public/controller/

```
app.controller('CustomCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
}]);
```

**test.html** this is my "template"

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        {{test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/CustomCtrl.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Flapper News</h1>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="border: 1px solid black">
                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just need that my test.html has is own controller CustomCtrl (I tried to print Hello World! but it prints {{test}} )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve.

I needed to import with

```
<script src="controller/CustomCtrl.js"></script>
```

in **index.html** , to fix with

```
angular.module('flapperNews').controller('CustomCtrl', CustomCtrl);
```

at the top of the CustomCtrl.
And everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for your test state you've specified the name of the controller as the javascript file that contains it rather than as the name of the controller function.

Comment: I tried even without .js but still {{test}} remain unbinded.

Comment: What controller are you expecting your test state to use? Actually, before you get too far down this road, I'd recommend that you see what the bible has to say about this: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md. Since you're just getting started, in particular, it's advisable to stay away from referencing $scope and use "ControllerAs" syntax instead.

Comment: I need test.html to use MainCtrl.js controller.
Actually I'm using a full web application with nodejs, angularjs, cassandra and go, but I found it built and now I need to start from scratch

Comment: I assume mainctrl.js is the same controller referenced in your home state. If not, I would also recommend avoiding using the duplicate controller names. If it is the same controller and it works in your home state, controller: 'MainCtrl' should work there as well. If it doesn't your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: No, it isn't the same controller. I changed name and edited the question to reflect it

Comment: Where is the script tag that loads the javascript that contains the controller located then? IIRC, it can't be in test.html since that's too late. I'd make sure you're referencing it in index.html and that it's loading as expected.

Comment: That's probably the part I'm missing and I'm looking for. Where do I have to put it? Should I put some  `<script src="controller/MainCtrl.js"></script>` ??

Comment: Yes, generally for an angular app you load all of your scripts in your index.html after you load angular.

Comment: Added index.html with the suggested edit but still no bind. Sorry for time wasting, I'm really stuck

Comment: Probably best to put it all in a Codepen at this point. You just need the client side code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109477/discussion-between-a-ndrea-and-mike-feltman).